# How To Get All The Favorites In Salesforce?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, api, ui

I am using as reference this documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_favorites.htm
And it says that by doing an HTTP GET request to this url "/ui-api/favorites" it should retrieve "all of a user’s favorites.". But it seems it doesn't work.
I tried the following code in Execute Anonymous and received the error "System.HttpResponse[Status=Unauthorized, StatusCode=401]"

This is the code I tried in the sandbox, by the way I included some favorites to my user so it should retrieve something.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
string host = 'https://AAAAA.my.salesforce.com';

String endpoint = host +'/services/data/v45.0/ui-api/favorites';
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setEndpoint(endpoint);

Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

system.debug(res);
```

Does anyone know if the Favorite API is still in use? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In order to call standard API you have to authenticate yourself, indeed the [HTTP Status Code 401](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401)

> indicates that the client **request has not been completed because it lacks valid authentication credentials** for the requested resource

Since you're trying it in Anonymous console, you could use your own session id and you can get it calling [`UserInfo.getSessionId()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm#apex_System_UserInfo_getSessionId).
Once you retrieved it, you must set the `Authorization` header in the HTTPRequest: `req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());`

By the way, instead of hardcoding your host, you can call [`URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_url.htm#apex_System_URL_getSalesforceBaseUrl)

The whole script will look like this:

```java
String host = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm(); // https://yourdomain.salesforce.com
String path = '/services/data/v55.0/ui-api/favorites';
String endpoint = host + path;

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setEndpoint(endpoint);

Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

Integer statusCode = res.getStatusCode();
String responseBody = res.getBody();
System.debug(statusCode);
System.debug(responseBody);
```

The expected status code is 200 and the body will hold a list of [Favorite](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_responses_favorite.htm#ui_api_responses_favorite)